# Why is it fast to create a dictionary (or 4) from thousands of points of data, but it is very slow to categorize data from the dict.keys() method?

Tags: python, csv, big-o

I have a csv file of social data with around 80,000 rows.  The data is organized in 4 columns - broadly, "Source", "Target", "Connection Type", "Citation".  There are 20 different categories of citations, so I wrote a script in Python to shuffle the data into 20 different dictionaries so that I can stratify and play with the data by the connection type.  This is an example of a dictionary I'm setting up:

```
with open("FBDatatoAnalyse_CSV.csv", "rU") as csvfile:

counter = 0

print "Stage 2 - making FB data dictionary + counting target occurrences"

reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=str(u','))
for line in reader: 
    print counter

    sourceword = cleaner(line[0]) #the facebook link

    relationship = cleaner(line[1]) #name of relaitonship

    targetword = cleaner(line[2]) #who is the target?

    citation = cleaner(line[4]) #the citation

    if relationship == "Friend":
        if sourceword not in frienddict.keys():
            frienddict[sourceword] = [(targetword, relationship)]
        else:
            frienddict[sourceword].append((targetword, relationship))
```

However, I later wrote a modifier that will remove any tuples from the values of any of the citation dictionaries that do not have enough connections to other keys (don't appear as values for other keys).  The input to dictmodifier is a list of dictionary items using the .items() method, and an int that specifies the number of minimum linkages.  The code is attached here:

```
def dictmodifier(dictionaryitems, minimumlinks):
modifier = {}
goodlist = []
finaldict = {}

print "starting dictionary"

counter = 0

for tuple in dictionaryitems: #in format [(source, [(target, relationship), (target, relationship)] ), (source, [(target, relationship), (target, relationship)])]
    #print tuple
    for item in tuple[1]:
        print counter
        if item[0] not in modifier.keys(): #target
            modifier[item[0]] = 1
            counter += 1
        else:
            modifier[item[0]] += 1
            counter += 1

print "dictionary compiled"

for target in modifier.items():
    if target[1] >= minimumlinks:
        goodlist.append(target[0])

print "list of qualifiers made"

counter = 0

for (k,v) in dictionaryitems: 
    for tuple in v:
        if tuple[0] in goodlist:
            print counter
            if k not in finaldict.keys():
                finaldict[k] = [tuple]
                counter += 1
            else:
                finaldict[k].append(tuple) 
                counter += 1

return finaldict.items()
```

My question is:  it seems to take under 5 seconds to create one of the category dictionaries from 80K rows of data, but it takes around 5 minutes to analyze the dictionary.keys() as an input in "dictmodifier".  Why would this be?  I've done a bit of looking into big O notation but I don't take those classes until next semester in uni.  Thanks in advance, and please be kind, as I am just learning!

Comment: Stop calling `keys`.

Comment: The `.keys()` method returns a list of keys (not a generator). What happens if you change the relevant line to `if k not in finaldict:`?

Also, you should look into `collections.defaultdict`, it looks like you are trying to emulate its behavior.

Comment: You're constantly calling `keys()`, which constructs huge lists that are only to be iterated over and then destroyed.

Comment: Another optimization would be to make `goodlist` a set.  `tuple[0] in goodlist` has to check every item in `goodlist` in order to evaluate as false.  It's an O(n) operation.  Testing membership in a set is on average an O(1) operation.